# Idea Http Client - Reusing Requests

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, web-api-testing, java-http-client

I'm interested in starting to use the Idea Http Client for API testing. I'm currently facing a challenge. I have a set of requests or a sequence of requests that I would like to execute within other test sequences because they tend to be repetitive in most cases. Is there a way to import one .http file with requests into another, or any other option for reusing requests?

I couldn't find any helpful information about this issue in the documentation or online. I attempted to import a .http file into the JavaScript pre-request script, but it didn't work as expected.

Ideally, I would like to execute a sequence of requests from one HTTP file and include/import another file with requests either at the beginning or in the middle of this sequence. Alternatively, I'm open to exploring different solutions to achieve this.

Comment: There is related feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297808. Please follow it for updates.